# Facebook Javascript SDK - List Status Updates

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I'm developing a site that needs to just use the javascript API for Facebook to list a pages status updates. The FB API docs aren't terribly useful and I'm not even sure how to authenticate myself from my localhost.

Can you simply specify a user ID (the page in this case) and list its status updates provided its a public site? Even stepping through shows that the async calls to FB don't respond at all which suggests I've not specified my app ID correctly.

This is what I've got so far:

```
    <script>
      window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
          appId      : 'myappid', // App ID
          channelUrl : 'http://localhost:3000/channel.html', // Channel File
          status     : false, // check login status
          cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
          xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
        });

        // Additional initialization code here
        FB.api(
            {
                method: 'fql.query',
                query: 'SELECT message FROM stream WHERE source_id=1'
            },
            function(data) {
                alert(data);
            }
        );
      };

      // Load the SDK Asynchronously
      (function(d){
         var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
         js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
         js.src = "http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
         d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
       }(document));


    </script>
```

So my question is, can I stream any old page? I need something to test it with really. The above code doesn't work because of the way I've set my app up, and I don't own a page I'm requesting.

Any clues?

Answer (score 0):

1. You want to use the FB.getLoginStatus() function call before making a call to the FB.api() call.  You need to be sure the user is logged in.
2. If the page administrator is not logged in, then you will call FB.login, requesting the manage_pages and read_stream permissions.
3. Once you have the page administrator logged in, then you call `FB.api('me/accouts', 'get', callback)` to get teh list of pages they manage.
4. Then within that list of pages, there will be a page access token.  For each page, use the associated page access token to query `me/feed`.

Comment: Basically, the requirement is to list status updates for a page without a user having to be logged in. If you're saying that you must be logged in, then I'll likely use the RSS feed instead.

Comment: You must have a valid page access token to get a list of the pages' feed items.

Comment: Of course RSS doesn't need tokens.  The Graph API does. As well as the Javascript SDK (which uses the Graph API) mentioned in to title of this post.

Comment: Apologies, I was side tracking. My point is that Graph API is over-complicated for simply retrieving a feed of status updates which can be done via an RSS feed.

Comment: Anything that has security is going to be complex to use.  Anything that has **good** security is going to be **very** complex to use.